# How do I solve m boxes and n balls of different size problem recursively without sorting?

Tags: java, recursion

I've m boxes and n balls, each of different size. To give a simple example, let's say we have boxes of size: [10, 50, 20] and balls of size: [20, 10, 30, 10]. It can solved as follows,

Box 0 (Size 10) can store Ball 1 (Size 10) or Ball 3, but let's take Ball 1 for simplicity.

Box 1 (Size 50) can store Ball 0 (size 20) and Ball 2 (size 30)

Box 2 (Size 20) can store Ball 3 (size 10)

To solve this problem, I wrote following is the java code which is solved using sorting and in iterative way,

```
boolean canBallsFitInBoxes(int [] boxes, int [] balls) {
    Arrays.sort(boxes);
    Arrays.sort(balls);
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < balls.length && j < boxes.length;) {
      if(boxes[j] >= balls[i]){
        boxes[j] -= balls[i];
        i++;
      } else {
        j++;
      }
      
    }
    
    return i == balls.length;
}
```

I tested for few cases and above iterative solution works. I might have missed edge cases, happy to hear them correct it.

I tried recursive version by myself, but it works only if given arrays are already sorted or when boxes and arrays can be mapped easily like (boxes: [10, 50, 20] and balls: [10, 20, 30, 10]). Basically, when the order of boxes or balls is jumbled, I'm struggling to find a solution using recursion.

But I'm trying to find a generic way to solve this problem. Any suggestions how can I solve it recursively without explicit sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute-force, recursive way of solving the problem would be to take ball n and try to put it into each box. If the ball fits into the current box, recurse into using the next ball, otherwise try the next box.

```java
public boolean canBallsFitInBoxes(int[] boxes, int[] balls) {
  return fits(boxes, balls, 0);
}

private boolean fits(int[] boxes, int[] balls, int currentBall) {
  // More balls available?
  if (currentBall >= balls.length)
    // No -> all balls are inside boxes already -> success
    return true;
  // Check each box, trying to insert current ball
  for (int currentBox = 0; currentBox < boxes.length; currentBox++) {
    // Does ball fit into box?
    if (boxes[currentBox] >= balls[currentBall]) {
      // Yes -> put ball into box
      boxes[currentBox] -= balls[currentBall];
      // Proceed to remaining balls (recursively)
      if (fits(boxes, balls, currentBall + 1))
        // All remaining balls fit -> success
        return true;
      else
        // At least one of the remaining balls does not fit -> remove current ball from box again
        boxes[currentBox] += balls[currentBall];
    }
  }
  // All tries for this ball failed -> back-trace
  return false;
}
```

If you do not like the success check at the beginning of the recursive method and would rather prefer to check before recursing, you could also use:

```java
private boolean fits(int[] boxes, int[] balls, int currentBall) {
  // Check each box, trying to insert current ball
  for (int currentBox = 0; currentBox < boxes.length; currentBox++) {
    // Does ball fit into box?
    if (boxes[currentBox] >= balls[currentBall]) {
      // Yes -> put ball into box
      boxes[currentBox] -= balls[currentBall];
      // If more balls are available, proceed to remaining balls (recursively)
      if (currentBall + 1 >= balls.length || fits(boxes, balls, currentBall + 1))
        // All remaining balls fit -> success
        return true;
      else
        // At least one of the remaining balls does not fit -> remove current ball from box again
        boxes[currentBox] += balls[currentBall];
    }
  }
  // All tries for this ball failed -> back-trace
  return false;
}
```

Feel free to ask, if you do not understand the algorithm.

Comment: I understand most of it, but why did you do `boxes[currentBox] += balls[currentBall];`? I mean why are you increasing the boxes size?

Comment: Oh.. I think, I get it. To handle unfit balls? So that you can retry those boxes? I think I was missing this in my recursive call!

Comment: I do not understand your question. My solution covers balls which do not fit. The algorithm does the usual two things commonly seen in recursive solutions: dive deeper in order to continue a promising search and back-track in case of a failure.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. Can I ask you a follow-up? How can I find all the possible combinations of boxes and balls? Basically, don't return true and add it to a list of combination?

Comment: Actually, @Abhishek, SO is a Q/A platform, not a platform to ask others to write all the code for you. I only answered the question because I saw that at least you had implemented the non-recursive version before, and even in a nice and efficient way. So I wrote the whole recursive algorithm for you, instead of asking you to show your own try and help you fix it, as is my usual habit. Now you are asking me a second question, which would again require me to implement the full algorithm for you. Sorry, this is not some free version of UpWork. A user with 6.6k reputation should know that.

Comment: **Update:** Even though I think it makes the code a little bit harder to read, I commented each line for both variants, just in case other readers have difficulties understanding what the algorithm does. I think it looks ugly now, but it is always easier to remove the comments than to add them if you do not understand what the code does.